# Centering Image in DIV horizontally and vertically - cut off overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center the images both vertically and horizontally (so we see the center/middle) of the image in the containing div. And cut off any extra overflow. I have it working pretty good right now, but the images are not centered yet. Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/4/

I have looked at ALL of the similar stackoverflow questions, but none of those solutions have worked in my scenario. I have also looked all over the internet for a solution. This is my last resort.

I can't use any javascript for this project. I need a pure css solution.

```
.squaregallerywrap {
width:  285px; 
height: 285px;
}

.squaregallerywrap img {
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
max-height: 285px;
display:block;
margin:auto;
}

li {    
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/5/

Just add the following to the image:

```
.squaregallerywrap img{
  position:relative;
  left:50%;
  -moz-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
  -o-transform:translateX(-50%);
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you. It's almost perfect. The strangest thing is happening and I can't figure out why. There seems to be a 1px white space before 3 of the images (the universe pic and the 2 of the women). Any chance what you did created that space?

Comment: It seems the commonality between these 3 images is that they are all have larger height than width.

Comment: So I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: For those that want the answer to this little 1px white space problem. I fixed it by using max-height: 286px;
min-width: 286px; I have no idea why I need 286px instead of 285px, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `background-position: center` property. Just modify your code as following,

In HTML,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="squaregallerywrap" style="background-image:url('http://smartyet.com/assets/trail-blazer/images/gallery/2/1.jpg')"> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="squaregallerywrap" style="background-image:url('http://smartyet.com/assets/trail-blazer/images/gallery/2/2.jpg')"> </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And so on.

In CSS,

```
.squaregallerywrap {
    width:  285px; 
    height: 285px;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}


li {    
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all linear;
    transition: 0.4s all linear;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle...http://jsfiddle.net/pp74fb7b/6/